# Как сделать чтобы выбор одного из элементов списка ul li влиял на показ одного из скрытых списков ul?

Tags: javascript, html, css3

Помогите пожалуйста.
У меня есть список с фильмами. Нажав на фильм, нужно чтобы погружался список с его частями (1 часть, 2 чать и тп.) остальные все списки скрытые пока их не выберут.

```css
.selectvalue {
    display:none;
 }
 
 .selectvalue.active {
    display:block;
 }
```

```html
<div class="selectlink">
    <div class="selectlink-control">Список фильмов</div>
          <ul>
             <li><a href="#">Гарри Поттер</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Хоббит</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Властелин Колец</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Звездные войны</a></li> 
          </ul>
     </div>
</div>

<div class="selectvalue active">
    <div class="selectlink-control">Гарри Поттер</div>
          <ul>
             <li><a href="#">1 часть</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">2 часть</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">3 часть</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">4 часть</a></li> 
          </ul>
     </div>
</div>

<div class="selectvalue">
    <div class="selectlink-control">Хоббит</div>
          <ul>
             <li><a href="#">1 часть</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">2 часть</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">3 часть</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">4 часть</a></li> 
          </ul>
     </div>
</div>

<div class="selectvalue">
    <div class="selectlink-control">Властерин Колец</div>
          <ul>
             <li><a href="#">1 часть</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">2 часть</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">3 часть</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">4 часть</a></li> 
          </ul>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Если вам помог мой ответ, то пожалуйста можете выбрать его как "Правильный ответ" или если остались вопросы по вопросу, то можете задать мне их я обязательно на них отвечу :)

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать чтобы не по индексу нажатие было javascript:getParts(0) а если к каждому li класс поставить?

Comment: Добавил в ответ вариант без `javascript:getParts()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот **примерный** код, но сразу хочу сказать, что я не специалист на `js` так что может есть способ и изящней.

```js
let prevPart = -1;
function getParts(index){
    let parts = document.getElementsByClassName('selectvalue');
  if(index < parts.length && !parts[index].classList.contains('active')){
    parts[index].classList.add('active');
    if(prevPart != -1)
        parts[prevPart].classList.remove('active');
    prevPart = index;
  }
}
```

```css
.selectvalue {
    display:none;
 }
 
 .selectvalue.active {
    display:block;
 }
```

```html
<div class="selectlink">
    <div class="selectlink-control">Список фильмов</div>
          <ul>
             <li><a href="#" onclick="javascript:getParts(0)">Гарри Поттер</a></li>
             <li><a href="#" onclick="javascript:getParts(1)">Хоббит</a></li>
             <li><a href="#" onclick="javascript:getParts(2)">Властелин Колец</a></li>
             <li><a href="#" onclick="javascript:getParts(3)">Звездные войны</a></li> 
          </ul>
     </div>
</div>

<div class="selectvalue">
    <div class="selectlink-control">Гарри Поттер</div>
          <ul>
             <li><a href="#">1 часть Гарри Поттер</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">2 часть</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">3 часть</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">4 часть</a></li> 
          </ul>
     </div>
</div>

<div class="selectvalue">
    <div class="selectlink-control">Хоббит</div>
          <ul>
             <li><a href="#">1 часть Хоббит</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">2 часть</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">3 часть</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">4 часть</a></li> 
          </ul>
     </div>
</div>

<div class="selectvalue">
    <div class="selectlink-control">Властелин Колец</div>
          <ul>
             <li><a href="#">1 часть Властелин Колец</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">2 часть</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">3 часть</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">4 часть</a></li> 
          </ul>
     </div>
</div>
```

Или вот версия без `javascript:getParts()`:

```js
const films = document.getElementsByClassName("selectlink-control")[0].getElementsByTagName("li");

for (var i = 0; i < films.length; i++) {
    films[i].addEventListener('click', getParts, false);
}

let prevPart = -1;
function getParts(event){
  var child = event.toElement.parentNode;
  var parent = child.parentNode;
  //Находим индекс нажатого фильма в списке
  var index = Array.prototype.indexOf.call(parent.children, child);
  let parts = document.getElementsByClassName('selectvalue');
  if(index < parts.length && !parts[index].classList.contains('active')){
    parts[index].classList.add('active');
    if(prevPart != -1)
        parts[prevPart].classList.remove('active');
    prevPart = index;
  }
}
```

```css
.selectvalue {
    display:none;
 }
 
 .selectvalue.active {
    display:block;
 }
```

```html
<div class="selectlink">
    <div class="selectlink-control">
        Список фильмов
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Гарри Поттер</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Хоббит</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Властелин Колец</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Звездные войны</a></li> 
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="selectvalue">
    <div class="selectlink-control">Гарри Поттер</div>
          <ul>
             <li><a href="#">1 часть Гарри Поттер</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">2 часть</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">3 часть</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">4 часть</a></li> 
          </ul>
     </div>
</div>

<div class="selectvalue">
    <div class="selectlink-control">Хоббит</div>
          <ul>
             <li><a href="#">1 часть Хоббит</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">2 часть</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">3 часть</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">4 часть</a></li> 
          </ul>
     </div>
</div>

<div class="selectvalue">
    <div class="selectlink-control">Властелин Колец</div>
          <ul>
             <li><a href="#">1 часть Властелин Колец</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">2 часть</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">3 часть</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">4 часть</a></li> 
          </ul>
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Я бы сделал так:

Каждому элементу списка с фильмами добавить уникальные id (potter, hobbit, ring, star ).

И эти же значения присвоить как класс в соответствующий блок со списком частей фильма.

```
<div class="selectlink">
    <div class="selectlink-control">Список фильмов</div>
          <ul>
             <li id="potter"><a href="#">Гарри Поттер</a></li>
             <li id="hobbit"><a href="#">Хоббит</a></li>
             <li id="ring"><a href="#">Властелин Колец</a></li>
             <li id="star"><a href="#">Звездные войны</a></li> 
          </ul>
     </div>
</div>

<div class="selectvalue active potter">
    <div class="selectlink-control">Гарри Поттер</div>
          <ul>
             ...
          </ul>
     </div>
</div>

<div class="selectvalue hobbit">
    <div class="selectlink-control">Хоббит</div>
          <ul>
             ... 
          </ul>
     </div>
</div>

<div class="selectvalue ring">
    <div class="selectlink-control">Властерин Колец</div>
          <ul>
             ... 
          </ul>
     </div>
</div>

<div class="selectvalue star">
    <div class="selectlink-control">Звездные войны</div>
          <ul>
             ... 
          </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

А потом по клику на название фильма скрывать все списки и показывать тот у которого класс совпадает с id фильма по которому кликнули.

```
const filmList = [...document.querySelectorAll('.selectlink li')];
const allLists = [...document.querySelectorAll('.selectvalue')];

filmList.forEach(film => {
    const filmClass = film.id;
    film.addEventListener('click', e => {
        allLists.forEach(el => el.classList.remove('active'));
        document.querySelector('.' + filmClass).classList.add('active');
    });
});
```

Ну или если без добавления классов и id, то можно так:

```
const filmList = [...document.querySelectorAll('.selectlink li')];
const allLists = [...document.querySelectorAll('.selectvalue')];

filmList.forEach((film, index) => {
    film.addEventListener('click', e => {
        allLists.forEach((el, idx) => {
            index == idx ? el.classList.add('active') : el.classList.remove('active');
        });
    });
});
```

Но этот вариант будет работать только если порядок фильмов совпадает с порядком блоков с частями этих фильмов.